# Compare filenames with different encoding in Octave

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, octave, filenames

I'm trying to accomplish following task in Octave:

1. Read filename from text file
2. Search for this file in particular location on hard drive

My script works for most files, but for certain files containing unicode characters I'm unable to match the filename from textfile with filename as it appears in the file system.

Filenames in textfile are in UTF-8 encoding and I read them in Octave with function fgetl().
Filenames from file system are obtained via function readdir(). I'm on Windows, NTFS file system.

For example, one problematic filename contains character "Č".

When printed out in Octave console, the characters appear exactly the same. However, a HEX viewer reveals that the characters are not actually the same. In the first case the character is encoded as 0x010C, in the second case as 0x0043 + 0x030C. Comparing both of them via strcmp() fails, of course.

What I tried to do is to omitt all non-ASCII characters from the filename and then compare them. But this didn't work, probably because in the second variant the first part of the character (0x0043) is actually ASCII.

Now I'm looking for some way of converting one format to another to be able to compare them. Any ideas?

EDIT:
As I discovered later, the character Č in the filename on Windows is actually written as C+ˇ, which is just another way you can write that character. So the difference probably insn't in encoding standard, but in 2 different ways to achieve 1 visible character (glyph).

This question basically then changes to a task of matching characters written "at once" and corresponding pair of letter+combining character.

Comment: A solution is known as [Unicode normalization](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). For instance: in Powershell, `[char[]]'Č'.Normalize('FormC')` returns `Č` (_Latin Capital Letter C With Caron_) while `[char[]]'Č'.Normalize('FormD')` returns `C` and `̌` (_Latin Capital Letter C_ and _Combining Caron_). Or `unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr)` in Python…

Comment: @simonov not an answer to your question, but I assume you are using the GUI. The graphical console does not (yet) support unicode. But if you run octave-cli from a normal unicode-supporting terminal, you will find out that it prints things properly in this case. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777529/4183191)

Comment: Also, which version of octave are you using. I'm using v5.2.0 on linux and can type and readdir files with č in their name etc just fine. I cannot replicate this bug I'm afraid. Perhaps you'd like to make a testcase and include some debugging info? As for the question itself (possibly XY problem, but nevermind), you might find octave's "unicode2native", "native2unicode" and "unicode_idx" functions useful.

Comment: I'm using Octave 5.1.0. I did some experiments with the native2unicode and unicode_idx functions (thanks for the hint) and now I think that the Č in the windows filename is actually written as C+ˇ (with combining character). So this probably isn't a bug in readdir function. I will update my question to reflect this.