# How to format for copy and paste in Octave

Tags: format, octave, symbolic-math

My question is since Octave sometimes outputs in symbolic like

```
    s     a
   --- - ---
    4     4
```

I just want it to show like

```
s/4-a/4
```

so I can copy and paste it for other scripts.
I am sure this is simple but could not find anywhere both in documentation and site.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62777529/4183191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you want is

```
sympref display flat
```

Have a look at the documentation here for more info:

- https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/sympref.html (look at the display section)
- https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/pretty.html